# How to arrange glyphicons inside a table header inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I've a bootstrap table with glyphicons in it's heading. I am unable align them in inline when the screen is small/medium.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>First Name</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>Last Name</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>Username</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>First Name</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>Last Name</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>Username</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>First Name</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>Last Name</span></th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span><span>Username</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wt5mdwe5/)</kbd>

Comment: You want them on 1 line? ... like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/wt5mdwe5/1/

Comment: Or just the text in the 2:nd span ... like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/wt5mdwe5/3/

Comment: I don't want the overflow scroll for bottom. I will enclose that table inside a `row`

Comment: So how should a user get access to the part that gets hidden if no scroll is available?

Comment: I think you need to post an image showing how you want that fiddle to look

Answer (score 0):

They `aligned` to `bottom` as default by `bootstrap`, if you want to `align` them `top` you can override this

```
.table>thead>tr>th{vertical-align:bottom}
```

Add this to your css :

```
.table.table-striped>thead>tr>th{vertical-align:top}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wt5mdwe5/2/